# Find specific element in DOM tree?

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML code so far:

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="feature_plus">
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="feature_content">
    <p>test 1</p>
</div>

<div class="span4">
    <div class="feature_plus">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature_content">
    <p>test 2</p>
</div>

<div class="span4">
    <div class="feature_plus">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature_content">
    <p>test 3</p>
</div>
```

In order to display the content of a tooltip (and to do other things with jQuery), I'd like to know how I can find the content of the next `.feature_content` from each `.feature_plus`.

Edit : So I'm going to be more precise about it : I'm using Qtip2 and here is my code which is not working :

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('.feature_plus').qtip({
        content: {
             text: $(this).parent().next('.feature_content')
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-rounded qtip-shadow'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top left',  // Position my top left...
            at: 'bottom right' // at the bottom right of...
        }
     });
 });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) refers in my first post to the qtip generated itself.

So I had to think differently using jquery's each(), here is the solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.feature_plus').each(function () {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).parent().next('.feature_content')
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-rounded qtip-shadow'
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top left', // Position my top left...
                at: 'bottom right' // at the bottom right of...
            },
            show: {
                event: 'click',
                solo: true
            },
            hide: {
                event: false
            },
            events: {
                show: function (event, api) {
                    // Trying to hide the elem triggering qtip
                    $(this).hide();
                },
                hide: function (event, api) {
                    // Trying to show the elem triggering qtip on qtip hide
                    $(this).show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering why it wasn't working either. Apparently qtip doesn't handle $(this) the same way jQuery handles it. So in order to use it within a class for multiple tool tips, you need to wrap it in a .each just as you have shown here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
$('.feature_plus').parent().next('.feature_content').html();
```

If that's what the layout would be like each time.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngf8u/)

Comment: Hello thanks for your effort, I've edited my question to be more precise. I've tried what you've written but it's not working, maybe it's because I'm using $(this) I don't know :-)

Comment: @HugoTrial Check what the value of $(this) is. I don't know how qtip operates so you'll need to provide me a jsFiddle using it or something

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".feature_plus").parent().next(".feature_content").html()
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your effort, I've edited my question to be more precise. I've tried what you've written but it's not working, maybe it's because I'm using $(this) I don't know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.feature_plus').parent().next().html();
```

Comment: please look at [answer]